# Do you need to cook a casserole with raw eggs before you freeze it?

Tags: food-safety, cooking-time

I made a casserole yesterday that contains cooked pasta, cooked quinoa, dairy products, spinach and raw eggs. It is assembled and the baked at 350 for 30 minutes.

I am planning on making it again this weekend to freeze. Since the only raw ingredient is the eggs would it be okay to assemble it then freeze and cook the eggs when I am thawing it or should I cook it both now and after I bring it out of the freezer?

Comment: Is it served with the eggs raw or just assembled that way and then baked before serving?

Comment: sorry it is assembled that way then baked for 30 minutes at 350.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely fine, especially if the eggs are pasteurised. I've seen plenty of recipes that have raw egg in them that say it;s fine to freeze them. You can even freeze eggs (that have been mixed up a little) for up to three months. So yes, I'd say freeze it as soon as possible. Also, if you were concerned about freezing the quinoa that will fine as well (a lot of people don't know you can store grains in the freezer).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's probably fine as long as you don't delay putting it in the freezer. To be on the safe side, you might want to let the cooked ingredients cool, before you mix in the egg.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can freeze raw eggs, I see no reason you couldn't freeze a casserole that contains them.  Make sure all your ingredients are cold before putting in the freezer, or adding the eggs.